# Is there any function like contains from Java for PHP?

Tags: java, php

I would like to know if is there any function that search a string within string and return boolean value in PHP, telling if the string contains or not, like the method contains in Java?

Comment: The manual is a good place to discover which functions exist: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I checked it out but I can't find same function

Comment: Without any real php experience i just clicked the function list link from Oli and got a bit shocked. From a Java point of view i always wonder how people could remember these function names. Without the text on the side i would have no idea what many of these functions would do.

Comment: @micha I agree, most of function name are not totally easy to understand. I would need to read each function description to understand it :S

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `strpos()`, http://php.net/strpos

```
$str = "This is a sample string.";
$findMe = "sample";

if (strpos($str, $findMe) !== false) {
    // you found me!
}
```

Comment: Strict compare with false here is a need, you can't just do `!strpos($str, $findMe)` because if the position is 0, it will translated to false in php